# Die roll combinatorics and Yahtzee conundrum

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

While working out number of ways of getting different outcomes from a $6$ faced die rolled $6$ times, I stumbled upon a simplified approach, illustrated by number of ways to get the patterns below:

$3-1-1-1-0-0\;$ of a kind : $\binom{6}{3,1,1,1,0,0}\binom{6}{3,2}= 7200$
$2-2-1-1-0-0\;$ of a kind : $\binom{6}{2,2,1,1,0,0}\binom{6}{2,2,2}= 16,200$

However, it doesn't seem to work for Yahtzee, where a six faced die is thrown **five** times,
i.e. when the # of die faces $n \ne$ # of tosses $k$ .

I am not a mathematician, and my questions are:

$1.$ Why does it work at all when $n = k?$
$2.$ Why shouldn't it work when $n \ne k?$

*PS*
I was making a persistent error in the Yahtzee computations, so I shall be posting an answer comparing the usual way of computations for Yahtzee, and the abbreviated approach, just for reference.

Comment: Hi. What is the "simplified approach" ? How are you getting the second factor (like 6 choose 3,2)

Comment: $1$ is repeated thrice, and $0$, twice in the pattern. To see that it is "simplified", see how Yahtzee computations are normally done, at http://homepages.rpi.edu/~bennek/class/probold/handouts/Lec_3.5-08.pdf

Comment: If for a Yahtzee "3-of-a-kind plus two distinct numbers", we write $3-1-1-0-0-0$ then the answer is $\binom{5}{3,1,1,0,0,0}\binom{6}{3,2,1}=1200$, so it is the same kind of pattern isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, I had kept on making a stupid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of computing number of various kinds of outcomes in Yahtzee (rolling a $6$ faced die $5$ times) goes something like this:

*For $3$ of a kind and two distinct rolls, i.e. pattern $3-1-1$:*

Pick the $3$ of a kind: $6$
Pick the $2$ singletons: $\binom52 = 10$
Arrange the $3$ of a kind: $\binom53 = 10$
Arrange the singletons: $2$
Answer: $6\cdot10\cdot10\cdot2 = 1200$

This can be simplified as under:
Write the pattern in $6$ spaces as $3-1-1-0-0-0$
Write the answer as the product of $2$ multinomial coefficients representing *choose* and *permute*

$\binom{6}{3,2,1}\binom{5}{3,1,1}$ or if you so prefer, as $\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}\cdot\frac{5!}{3!1!1!} = 1200$

---

In $\binom{6}{3,2,1}$, $3,2,1$ represent the groups of three $0's,$ two $1's,$ and one $3$.